# Request comes empty in api request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an api point and it's like this:

```
[HttpPost("getJourneyPlanner")]
public IActionResult getJourneyPlanner2([FromBody] JourneyPlannerRequest_v2 jpr)
{
  ///codes
}
```

Request class:

```
 public class JourneyPlannerRequest_v2
 {
    public List<GeoPoint> fromLocations { get; set; } = new List<GeoPoint>();
    public List<GeoPoint> toLocations { get; set; } = new List<GeoPoint>();
 }

 public interface iSpatialPoint
 {
    double lat { get; set; }
    double lng { get; set; }
 }

 public class GeoPoint : iSpatialPoint
 {
    private GeoPoint(Point obj) : base(obj) { }

    public GeoPoint(double lat, double lng, int srid = 4326)
    {
       geoObj = new Point(lng, lat);
       geoObj.SRID = srid;
    }

    public double lat { get => geoObj.Coordinate.Y; set { } }

    public double lng { get => geoObj.Coordinate.X; set { } }
 }
```

This is my data when I send a request:

```
{  
   "fromLocations": [
     {
      "lat": 38.403639,
      "lng": 27.123452,
      "srid": 4326
     }
   ],
   "toLocations": [
     {
      "lat": 38.396371544658976,
      "lng": 27.132735550403595,
      "srid": 4326
     }
   ]
}
```

When I make the request I get the error 'jpr == null'. Why is my request class not drilling full. I think it is because of the GeoPoint class. Because I don't get an error when I send an empty list. Why am I having such a problem. What am I doing wrong. (The project is being developed with .net8.)

Comment: Try adding `[JsonConstructor]` attribute on `public GeoPoint(double lat, double lng, int srid = 4326)`

Comment: What's your  geoObj  ?

Comment: ` protected internal Geometry geoObj;` geoObj = Point.Empty; @Qing Guo

Comment: new Point(int x, int y) but your new Point(lng, lat) lng, lat are double. Do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try below one, it may work:

Json Request:

```json
"fromLocations": [
  {
    "lat": 38.403639,
    "lng": 27.123452,
    "srid": 4326
  }
],
```

In your `GeoPoint` class:

```
public double lat { get => geoObj.Coordinate.Y; set { } }
public double lng { get => geoObj.Coordinate.X; set { } }
```